# Windows non-ASCII file paths

Tags: c++, windows, fopen, non-ascii-characters

I am doing some experiment to a better understanding of conversion and have following code which is not working as expected

```
std::wstring inScriptPath = "non-ASCII file name"
using convert_type = std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>;
std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;
std::string my_path = converter.to_bytes(inScriptPath);

std::fstream myfile;
myfile.open(my_path.c_str(), ios::in); //open the file
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "Openning file for reading with fstream" << std::endl;
    myfile.close();
}



 FILE * pFile;
 pFile = fopen(my_path.c_str(), "r");
 if (pFile != NULL)
 {
    std::cout << "Openning file for reading with fopen" << std::endl;       
    fclose(pFile);
 }
```

I am expected that after converting wstring to string file open/fopen should work but it is not working.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. You could just pass the `wstring` to `open`

Comment: As I already told you on your previous question, passing a UTF-8 filename to `fopen` will only work if the active codepage of the process is UTF-8, which can be set in the manifest of the executable in Windows 10 only. In the particular case in which the active codepage is UTF-8, `fopen` will decode the filename to wide-character UTF-16, the native string format on the Windows platform. In older versions of Windows, UTF-8 is not supported as the active codepage, and you must pass a UTF-16 string to a wide-character function such as `wfopen`, `_wopen`, or `CreateFileW`.

Comment: `CreateFileA` and ANSI Win32 APIs operate on the current code page which is (usually) not UTF-8 so it'll never work that way. Use boost.nowide if you want portable code, otherwise you'll have to use Unicode functions in Windows (unless you're targeting just a small amount of Windows 10 machines)

Answer (score 0):

`char` and `wchar_t` are incompatible.  You can't convert from/to automatically at the C++ level, you have to use instead a function such as [WideCharToMultiByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte).

Just forget 8-bit strings in Windows. Always use unicode, `std::wstring`, `wchar_t`, `wfopen`, etc. Windows internally uses 16-bit wide chars. UTF-8 is not automatically converted.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I also tried to do the conversion with WideCharToMultiByte but it also not work. I understand that for windows it is better to use wstring, wchar_t, wfopen. But in any case if I have third party library which uses fopen I need to the conversion to string. Which as I understand not working case.

Comment: You have to convert them with MultiByteToWideChar(), or use the A-(ANSI) functions in windows.

Comment: I have wstring why to convert  MultiByteToWideChar()?
I need to pass wstring to the third party library which uses fopen so I need to convert it to WideCharToMultiByte.

Comment: @Lilit watch out the convertion, you probably have to use CP_ACP in WideCharToMultiByte.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Here is my code for conversion

Comment: string Unicode::ConvertFromUtf16ToUtf8(const wstring& wstr)
{

 string convertedString;
 int requiredSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr.c_str(), -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 if (requiredSize > 0)
 {
  vector<char> buffer(requiredSize);
  WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr.c_str(), -1, &buffer[0], requiredSize, 0, 0);
  convertedString.assign(buffer.begin(), buffer.end() - 1);
 }
 return convertedString;
}

Comment: If your wide string isn't representatble in your local codepage there isn't much you can do, you could try `GetShortPathNameW`